# copy constructor calling using "new"

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm quite new to C++.

I have read that the copy constructor is called when passing an object as an arguement to a function or when returning an object from a function and in initiallization of variables with assignment.
Can it be called also in this case, suppose D has copy constructor?

```
D* pd1 = new D;
D* pd2 = new D(*pd1);
```

Comment: What is the type of `pd1`?

Comment: @ecatmur, D type?

Comment: @RedRainbowGuy no, it's `D*`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes.**

Copy constructors can be called either implicitly or explicitly.

In this case it is explicitly called:

```
D* pd2 = new D(*pd1); //pd1 points to D object
```

In this case it is implicitly called:

```
D pd2 = *pd1; //pd1 points to D object
```

A copy constructor can not be called implicitly if it uses the `explicit` specifier.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Comment: Does this mean that `pd2` in `D pd2 = *pd1;` also is heap-allocated?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```
class copy {
public:
    copy(int a = 1) :i(a) {}
    copy(copy &c) :i(c.i) { std::cout << "I'm copied!"; }
private:
    int i;
};

int main() {
    copy c;
    // here the copy constructor is called
    // the string literal will be printed 
    auto p = new copy(c);
}
```

It's clear to see that "new copy(c)" calls the copy constructor.